# Using logical functions and rowSums together

Tags: r

I am trying to understand an R code I have inherited (see below).

```
sel <- which(rowSums(m3T3L1mRNA.tmp[,c(2,4)] == 20) != 2)
```

[image]

The output of this code essentially excludes all rows from this table (there are thousands of rows, only the first 5 have been shown) that have the value 20 (which in this table equates to NAs).

The code works fine, but I am having trouble interpreting the code. As I understand the code is asking to get the rowSum of rows that contain a value of "20" at columns 2 and 4 (which is 40) and select ones that do not sum up to 2.

Where does the value 2 come from? Shouldn't it be as below for the code to work as I think it should?

```
sel <- which(rowSums(m3T3L1mRNA.tmp[,c(2,4)] == 20) != 40)
```

Comment: When you run `rowSums` it's input is logical vector (`TRUE` and `FALSE` values), not original numeric values. Therefore if there are 2 `TRUE` in row you will get `2` (`TRUE == 1`).

Comment: @PoGibas Thanks! That's clarified my confusion. It also means that this code has selected rows that contain a "20" in columns 1 or 3 but not in columns 2 and 4 or ones that contain a "20" in 2 but not 4 (and vice versa). I've now modified the code to `sel1 <- which(rowSums(m3T3L1mRNA.tmp[,c(1:4)] == 20) < 1)` to exclude rows that have a "20" in any one of its column.

Comment: You can also try this: `which(rowSums(m3T3L1mRNA.tmp[, 1:4] == 20) == 0)` :-)

Comment: @PoGibas Cheers! ;)